# Audio of the tab disappear while capturing tab using TabCapture API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, audio-recording

I am testing a Tab Capture API to record audio of web page that contains a text to speech flash object. while recording a web page the playback audio disappear but sounds OK in the recorded file.

I am using the following MediaStream constraint to record video and audio.

```
var MediaStreamConstraint = {
            audio: true, 
            video: true, 
            videoConstraints: {
                mandatory: {
                    chromeMediaSource: 'tab',
                        minWidth: 640,
                        maxWidth: 640,
                        minHeight: 420,
                        maxHeight: 420

                }
            }
};
```

am i missing something in the stream constraint or there is some other solution to the problem?

Comment: Having the same problem... have you resolved this yet?

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, playing the audio from the captured MediaStream in the callback works:

```
chrome.tabCapture.capture(MediaStreamConstraint, gotStream);

function gotStream(stream) {
  window.audio = document.createElement("audio");
  window.audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  window.audio.play()
}
```

Comment: [CreateObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) no longer accepts media stream object and causes `TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.` We should use `audio.srcObject = stream` instead

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind to grant permissions in manifest file

```
"permissions": [
    "tabCapture",
    "activeTab",
    ...
  ],
```

The background.js should be something like this:

```
var recorder = new MRecordRTC();
function handleCapture(stream) {
recorder.addStream(stream);
recorder.mediaType = { video: true, audio: true };
recorder.startRecording();
}

var MediaStreamConstraint = {
audio: true,
video: true,
videoConstraints: {
    mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'tab',
        minWidth: 640,
        maxWidth: 640,
        minHeight: 420,
        maxHeight: 420
    }
}
};

function captureCurrentTab() {
chrome.tabCapture.capture(MediaStreamConstraint, handleCapture);
}

function stopCapturing() {
// stops the recording and save audio and video     
}
```

If these are not the case, could you please attach more related codes since the codes you attached look good with me.

Comment: Thanks gui47 for the answer, i am using the same code for capturing audio and video with exactly the same permissions in the manifest file, but the problem is that as soon as the capture method is called the actual playing audio of the application vanish.. as some one muted the audio

Comment: I'm getting `stream` as `null` any idea hwy this might be happening ? all the permissions are there as mentioned above

Comment: @aziz86, were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

In your background script's handleCapture function, try this to continue playback:

```js
var audio = new Audio(window.URL.createObjectURL(stream));
audio.play();
```

Answer (score -1):

only add the next lines

```
window.audio = document.createElement("audio");
window.audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
window.audio.play()
```

Comment: Adding only those lines would certainly not help anyone (what is `stream`?)

Comment: stream is the object MediaStream

Comment: From where? Again, you say "only add the next lines", by themselves they will just produce an error.